# SCSS for loop with odd syntax works but getting syntax errors

Tags: sass, webstorm

Hi i create a for loop to generate classes similar to how bootstrap does its grid system but with flexbox and i am wondering if anyone knows why im getting this error.

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .flex-#{$i} {
        flex: 0 #{$i} 8.333333333333333 * $i + % ;
        padding: 0 $default-spacing;
    }
}
```

it all compiles perfectly i just get a syntax error on this line

```
flex: 0 #{$i} 8.333333333333333 * $i + % ;
```

maybe its IDE base, im using the latest version of webstorm.

Any ideas?

Thanks, kieran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you you want concatenate a string must be quoted but you get a string:

**SASS**

```
flex: 0 #{$i} 8.333333333333333 * $i + "%"
```

**Output**

```
flex: 0 1 "8.33333%";
```

In your case is better multiplicate for **1%** to get a number with percentage unit

**SASS**

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .flex-#{$i} {
        flex: 0 #{$i} 8.333333333333333 * $i * 1% ;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
.flex-1 {
  flex: 0 1 8.33333%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 0 2 16.66667%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
 ...
```